# Set Martini Log Path

Tags: go, martini

How do I set the martini log path to some random file.
It is now displaying in console.

```
m := martini.Classic()
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attach a new logger to Martini:

```
f, err := os.OpenFile("logfile", os.O_RDWR | os.O_CREATE | os.O_APPEND, 0666)
if err != nil {
    t.Fatalf("error opening file: %v", err)
}
defer f.Close()

m.Map(log.New(f, "[martini]", log.LstdFlags))
```

Comment: Just to note that you'll probably want to rotate the log file at some point (using `logrotate` or a similar tool). No doubt @fabrizioM kept his example simple, but I figured it was worth stating.

Comment: Thanks fabrizioM and elithrar

Comment: I've not been able to get this to work.  The file is created but martini does not log into it.  Instead it still comes on the command line prefixed with [martini].

Comment: what is "t" in your case?